# google in-app subscription unexpected behavior

Tags: android, verification, subscriptions, in-app

I trying to test Android In-App Billing V3 to make subscription purchases.

Im aware of the following:
"Test subscription purchases recur daily, regardless of the product's subscription period."

but I noticed the following behavior:

1. A user buys a monthly subscription through google play, the client passes the information to the server. On the server side, I make an API call to google to get more info about the subscription.
2. I go to the Google play dashboard and cancel the subscription. (it changes from renewing on X to expire on X).
3. I buy the same subscription again but I have the following behavior:

   - Purchase token is the same as in #1. My assumption that the purchase
     token will be different.
   - autoRenewing is still set to false (even
     though google play dashboard shows "will renew on x").
   - expiryMills still shows the original expiration which is in the past (I resubscribed a couple of days later so I would expect the expiryMills to be updated)

Im not sure if this is the correct beahvior or not ...

I would expect the following: If im in within the period, so after the user cancels and then resubscribes, the autoRenewing will "true", and if im after the period, I will get a new purchase token so that the information I get from google api will match the google play dashboard.

Ofir

Comment: I've noted the same (using test subscriptions, I don't know with real subscription) and I would expect the renewing sets as true along the correct expiration date like you do. Unfortunately, I don't have clue why this is happening and if it's only a problem with test subscription.